# Delay loading of webpart

Tags: 2010, optimization

I have a visual webpart which do very heavy lifting. There's a lot of data manipulation and after heavy optimization the page still takes 16 seconds to load.

I want to know a way so that my page loads (Ribbon etc) even if my webpart is still in process. This is for aesthetics. Currently there's a blank page and it seems that nothing is happening.